# Use base struct as function argument in inheritance scenario

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

I want to build a somewhat flexible inheritance for different HLSL-Shaders. Sadly my planned route did not work, and i am wondering why. Here is what i am doing:

I have a base-struct and some structs which inherit from it:

```
struct baseStruct {};

struct childStruct1 : public baseStruct {
    int someInt1;
    int someInt2;
}

struct childStruct2 : public baseStruct {
    float someFloat1;
    bool someBool1;
}
```

And an abstract class with pure virtual functions declared like this:

```
class BaseClass {
    virtual void Function1(baseStruct& structVal) = 0;
    virtual void Function2(baseStruct& structVal) = 0;
}
```

This is the according child class:

```
class ChildClass {
    void Function1(baseStruct& structVal);
    void Function2(baseStruct& structVal);
}
```

Now i want to be able to call either of those functions with different structs, which have `baseStruct` as a parent like this:

```
childStruct1 cS1;
cS1.someInt1 = 5;
CS1.someInt2 = -3;

Function1(cS1);
```

The compiler is not complaining, but when i step through my program i noticed that the struct is filled with values before the function, but as soon as i step into my function the struct is empty. Now my first impression would be, that this happens because it gets "casted" to a `baseStruct`, which is empty.
Is there a way to achieve something like this, or am i doing something wrong? Maybe this is even possible and i fucked up somewhere else, but then why does the debugger say its empty?
Thank you!

Comment: `but as soon as i step into my function the struct is empty` How do you determine that? Are you looking at the structure in the debugger? Inside the function, the type of the parameter is `baseStruct&`, which doesn't have any members, so there's nothing for the debugger to show. How does the function plan to use the values of `cS1.someInt1` and `cS1.someInt2` (and if it doesn't plan to use them, then why do you care what they are?)

Comment: But what if i want to use those values defined before the function inside it? If baseStruct is empty, is there a way to access them? How do i cast it back?
EDIT: Those structs are effectively constant-buffers for the shader and are thus passed immediately to the shader.

Comment: You cast it back by using a cast, of course; e.g. `static_cast<childStruct1&>(structVal)`. The question is, how do you plan to know which type to cast to?

Comment: I just noticed this aswell. Might be not such a good idea then. Maybe with templating. I will see. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struct you see in the debugger is empty because when you enter Function1 the debugger 'forgets' any info about cs1 and knows just about baseStruct (which is empty).

If you do something like

```
childStruct *cs1 = reinterpret_cast<childStruct1>(&structVal) ;
```

yoy should see everything there.

But this takes to the real problem of you design: how do you tell, inside Funtion1 if you have received a childStruct1 or childStruct2?

Comment: Yes you are right. That really is a flaw. Thanks for your help!